# CMTimeMake crash when making video thumbnail

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to make a video thumbnail, and was following another tutorial here on SO. I'm sure I've done everything it told me to do, but it's still not working...

This is the error I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_CMTimeMake", referenced from:
  -[MainMenuController imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:] in MainMenuController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The code:

```
AVURLAsset* asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:movieUrl] options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator* imageGenerator = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:asset];
    pickedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMake(1, 1) actualTime:nil error:nil]];
```

Do any of you have any idea of what might be wrong?

I have included the AVFoundation Framework, just fyi...

Thanks in advance, Tom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CMTimeMake` is defined in the CoreMedia framework, so you probably have to add

```
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>
```

to your source code.